# Copying tables between databased with different authentication DB2

Tags: database, authentication, copy, db2, procedure

Hey StackOverflow community,

My question is as follows:
I have a table, say `USER_ADDR` with a bunch of columns in one database, say `DB001`
I need to copy the contents of this table(based on a criteria) to a similar table `USER_ADDR` (same name, yes) in another database `DB002` with a different userID and pwd.

I need to do this in a stored procedure that will be executed using a .net framework.
I tried this:

```
INSERT INTO "DB002".USER_ADDR (--column names--)  
SELECT * 
FROM "DB001".USER_ADDR 
WHERE ID = "APPLICATION_NO_IN";
```

I get:

> 0: Error occurred: [IBM][DB2/NT64] SQL0204N  "DB002.USER_ADDR" is an undefined name.  LINE NUMBER=15.  SQLSTATE=42704 : -204: IBM.Data.DB2: 42704

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance
Vashist

Comment: please provide your table schemas. also, is the use case for this something like a one time bulk load of lots of rows or something like inserting just one row but will need to be done repeatedly on an ongoing basis?

Comment: I tried it with the schemas too. This is triggered by an application completion. say, a "submit" button on an asp.net page.
 The data needs to be copied from the server to a mainframe database. they are on different servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm deleting my other answer after seeing the additional info about your use case. Load is mainly for bulk loads of large numbers of records.

in this case i'd recommend you do something like open connection1 in .Net to your data source, select the data and hold it in a .Net `DataTable`. If required, you can do that select in a stored proc that returns either individual column values for a single row or return a cursor (rowset) that contains all the columns (and rows). Then in .Net open connection2 and insert the data from the DataTable to your destination. Again, that can be done with a stored proc.

Comment: Thanks. This is a great suggestion. What are the data types I must use for:
a) output parameter for SP 1
b) input parameter for SP2
the datatable object that is..

Sorry if this might seem trivial.

Comment: Vikrant: I finally got this figured out this week. I used a slightly different method to copy data into the 2nd DB but it was inspired by your idea. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is using an external script that connects to both databases.
From just one database is not possible, at least you use, as already mentioned, Information integration (federation) or by exporting the data and then loading it.

Comment: I dont have federation enabled. How do I export & load data?
I know how they work individually, but I've never donea  cross database copy.

Comment: You simply export the data from a table in a given format, for example CSV (Comma separated value) and then, you import that file in the other database. CSV and DEL (delimited) are the mos popular formats to deal with data in flat files.